# How do i upgrade a module in a running NetBeans Platform application from commandline or script?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, hotdeploy

How do i upgrade a module in a running NetBeans Platform from commandline or script? When developing NetBeans Platform Apps in NetBeans IDE it is possible to hot deploy/update modules in a running instance of the application you are working on. How can i do this from ex commandline or an ANT script so i can do rapid development of NetBeans Platform application without using the NetBeans IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the same executable that us used to start the application but add the reload option and the path to the module that you want to reaload.

```
myapplication.sh --reload "com-company-mymodule.jar"
```

Comment: how do you do that from within the IDE 6.9?